# How to make .NET Core MSBuild to not generate an empty assembly for a metapackage project

Tags: msbuild, .net-core

I have a .NET Core meta-package project defined in `project.json`. It contains no code but just references to a few other sub-projects. This meta-package project exists for 2 purposes:

1. A NuGet meta-package can be produced that references to the NuGet packages of those sub-projects.
2. the top-level project can reference only to this meta-package project to chain the dependency to those sub-projects.

This works fine with `project.json` -- when building the meta-package project, all referenced sub-projects get built and the meta-package project itself doesn't produce anything.

Now with .NET Core SDK 1.0, I'm migrating from `project.json` to `.csproj` via `dotnet migrate`, and I find the behavior has changed -- building the meta-package project still get the referenced sub-project built, but itself starts to produce an empty assembly. This causes an empty `meta-package.dll` to appear in the publish folder of the top-level project, and I cannot simply remove it with an after-build target because it's also recorded in the generated `.deps.json` file, which makes it part of the TPA (trusted platform assemblies). So simply removing the empty assembly will cause the application to crash at startup.

Is there a way to not generate an empty assembly when building this meta-package project with MSBuild?

Answer (score 0):

Nuget packages are created with nuspec files. The new dotnet core based project system, is able to build these nuspec files, and packages for your class libraries. This does not negate that it wraps nuget, and nuspec files. If you wish to control how packages are made, and thus make packages with no dll's you must use nuget directly.

You can make a nuspec file that just has dependencies, you wish to take.

example nuspec file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>MetaPackageId</id>
    <version>$VERSION$</version>
    <authors>authors</authors>
    <owners>owners</owners>
    <licenseUrl>http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT</licenseUrl>
    <projectUrl>proj url</projectUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>
      desc
    </description>
    <summary>
      summary
    </summary>
    <releaseNotes>
    View the release notes on github
    </releaseNotes>
    <copyright></copyright>
    <tags>tags</tags>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency id="APackageDependency" version="1.0.0" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

then you can call nuget pack /path/to/my.nuspec

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use the property

```xml
    <PropertyGroup>
        <IncludeBuildOutput>false</IncludeBuildOutput>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

> **IncludeBuildOutput** - This Boolean value specifies whether the build output assemblies should be packed into the .nupkg file or not.